# Controller is not able to pass the response to the index.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to this. There are a couple of solutions posted for a similar problem but none of them helped.
I have posted below a very simple toy example that will help you to debug.

index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
port=3001

var controller = require('./controller');
app.use('/api', controller);
```

controller.js

```js
var model = require('./model')
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/bl', function(req, res) { 
    model.getData( function (err, objects) {
        if(err) return res.send(err);
        return res.status(200).json(objects);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

model.js

```js
const bl = {"hello":"world"}
const getData= (request, response) => {
    return(bl);
  }

module.exports = {
  getData
}
```

Issue:
invoking : http://localhost:3001/api/bl => no response
, console : no error

Note:

in my model.js, I am querying in the Postgres database, and I can see the results in console.log.

but I don't see any such result when I try to see data using console.log in controller.js. Similar behavior I observed in the above toy example

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return res.status(200).json(objects);`

Comment: sorry, that was typo in my question, I corrected it.

Comment: I suppose that you have something like `app.listen(port, () => 'listening at: ' + port)` at the end of `index.js` and that the server is running?

Answer (score 3):

I can see an error and something worrying me.

The error is in following two lines

```
// In controller.js
model.getData( function (err, objects) {

// In models.js
const getData= (request, response) => {
```

You define a function accepting two arguments `(request, response)` (both of them are objects) and than you call it passing only one argument of type function.

The thing worrying me is the `getData` function itself.

```
const bl = {"hello":"world"}
const getData= (request, response) => {
  return(bl);
}
```

Apart from parameters, it is a sync function, but in your question you pointed that in models.js you query in the Postgres database, and you can see the results in console.log; now you give us no details about how you query Postgress, but I suppose you are doing it with something asynchronous (probably [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)). The other relevant detail you didn't revealed is if you query Postgress inside or outside the body of getData function. I hope I'm wrong, but since in your example you are returning something define outside the body of the function, I have the doubt.

Let's consider only the good option, you query Postgress inside the body of the function, probably your complete getData function looks like follows.

```
const getData = (request, response) => {
  client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'], (err, res) => {
    // Here you get your message in console
    console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].message);
    client.end();
  })

  return something;
  // I don't know what, but fore sure something wrong
}
```

To solve both the problems you just need to fix getData (by chance or by cut&paste you are calling it in the right way in controller.js).

Let's start fixing its signature makeing it accept only one argument: the callback function:

```
const getData = (done) => {
```

then let's asynchronously "return" the data we got from Postgress through the `done` callback function.

```
const getData = (done) => {
  client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'], (err, res) => {
    // We can leave this for debugging purposes
    console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].message);
    // Here we are not handling errors from client.end()...
    // but we can neglect about this right now
    client.end();
    // Let's calle the callback function passing it the result
    done(err, res);
  })

  // There's nothing to return
}
```

It should be enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need a third argument, you will mostly see `callback` or just `cb` and execute it in the function and pass some data to it. The first parameter `false` will be the error argument later and `bl` will be the `objects` argument that is passed

```
const getData= (request, response, callback) => {
    callback(false, bl);
  }
```

and then pass `req` and `res` arguments to it:

```
model.getData(req, res, function (err, objects) {
    if(err) return res.send(err);
    return res.status(200).json(objects);
});
```

Or the modern way to do it with `async / await` you could return an promise

```
const getData= (request, response) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(someErrorAppear){
         reject("some error occured");
      }
      resolve(bl);
   })
}
```

Now you can go with `async / await`

```
router.get('/bl', async function(req, res) { 
    try {
       let objects = await model.getData(req, res);
       res.status(200).json(objects);
    }catch(err){
       res.send(err);
    }  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution to this.
Actually, the error is in model.js. Try below code:

```
const bl = {"hello":"world"}
const getData= (callback) => {
    callback (bl)
  }

module.exports = {
  getData
}
```